# Como fazer uma chamada de um script que está em outra pasta

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um processo na qual será necessário fazer um chamada em um script que está em um outro diretório.

Tenho um script que está no diretório /home/formiga/testes/mobile/myphone.sh

Se eu precisasse fazer esse fluxo no shell eu faria:

FORM_PATH="/home/formiga/testes/mobile/"
CHECK_CMP="$FORM_PATH/myphone.sh"

Como eu poderia fazer essa chamada no python?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Fala Formiga! Tudo bem?

Acredito que sua pergunta ficou muito aberta. Ao criar sua dúvida, lembre sempre de colocar mais detalhes, exemplos do seu código e descrever suas tentativas e erros. Para o código, você pode utilizar o `os.chdir()` para alterar o local do diretório atual.
Lembre-se de importar o módulo com o `import os`.

Ao mudar o diretório para o local do arquivo é possível utilizar algo para executar seu script como o  `subprocess` e seu método `run()` que executa comandos passados para ele em string